# AWS CodeBuild SAM esbuild method not working

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-codebuild, sam

I have a Lambda's API Gateway repo in CodeCommit and I build it with CLI with esbuild and it works fine (SAM BUILD and then SAM DEPLOY)

I want to integrate the building process with CodePipeline, so started to play around with CodeBuild, but when I run the build it says:

> File
> "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.9.5/lib/python3.9/site-packages/samcli/lib/build/workflow_config.py",
> line 133, in get_selector
> raise UnsupportedBuilderException("'{}' does not have a supported builder".format(specified_workflow))
> samcli.lib.build.workflow_config.UnsupportedBuilderException:
> 'esbuild' does not have a supported builder

My template Lambda looks like this:
*(I remove the properties in order to make it easier to read)*

```
BasicFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
    Metadata:
      BuildMethod: esbuild
      BuildProperties:
        Minify: false
        Target: "es2020"
        EntryPoints:
        - appBasic.ts
```

My buildspec.yml looks like this:

```
version: 0.2
phases:
  install:
    commands:
      - npm install
      - npm install esbuild
  build:
    commands:
      - sam build
      - sam deploy --no-confirm-changeset --no-fail-on-empty-changeset
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to have the esbuild working using CI/CD you need to make sure you have the esbuild package in the **"dependencies"** section in the package.json file. it will not work if it's located under the **"devDependencies"** section.

```
"dependencies": {
  "esbuild": "0.17.18"
},
```